# Auto-import references using paths from tsconfig

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I have some path references set up in tsconfig.json and would like to use those when auto-importing a new reference to a file. Right now, if I have a paths reference like:

```
"paths": {
      "tools/*": [ "../Frontend.Tools/*" ]
    }
```

When I hit `Ctrl+space` on a `ConfigurationModel` reference Visual Studio will do auto imports like

```
import { ConfigurationModel } from '../../../Frontend.Tools/configuration';
```

but what I want is

```
import { ConfigurationModel } from 'tools/configuration';
```

How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Formatting > General

`Module Specifier Preference`

The top option did what I wanted:

> Prefers using a non-relative import only if one is available that has fewer path segments than a relative import

[image]